# C popen fwrite buffer problems

Tags: c, imagemagick, mingw, stdin, popen

I use my C program to stream binary data to ImageMagick:

```
inbuf = popen(string, "wb");
setbuf(inbuf, NULL);                  /// !!! ///
fwrite(buffer, frame, 1, inbuf);
pclose(inbuf);
```

And ImageMagick doesn't always receive all data on windows (mingw). Without the setbuf command (disabling bufferization) it receives even less data and problem appears on Linux (gcc) as well.

When I dump just the same buffer to file everything works fine and all data is written to disk and I don't even have to disable buffering:

```
outbuf = fopen("temp\\tune.gray", "wb");
fwrite(buffer, frame, 1, outbuf);
fclose(outbuf);
```

I discovered that problem occurs when I send odd number of bytes :)  When I send even number everything works fine. I tried to write data not in bulk mode but splitting buffer to smaller portions, tried even sending data byte-by-byte - it doesn't help. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

fwrite returns the total number of bytes successfully written. You can write a loop which tests how many bytes are actually written, and proceed to next write operation (from the location which was successfully written) until the entire buffer is successfully written.

Comment: Tried that also. fwrite returns the correct number but ImageMagick doesn't get data. Maybe I should dive into its sources?

Comment: Okay @DEgorov are you using fwrite parameters correctly i.e. the above code of your should mean "array of frame sized elements where you send only 1 element". Second param is "size of structure sent" and third element is number of size element http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/fwrite/

Comment: Yes, everything is correct - buffer is a pointer to my data, frame is the size of data I need to send, so number is 1. I tried sending data in different portions (even 1 byte frame times) - doesn't help.